# Making object face another with rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I'm trying to make my spotlight face its target when I translate it. I've tried glm::lookAt() with limited success. Lets say the light is at (0, 16, 0) and facing the origin. I've read that I need to translate the light to the origin, apply the rotation, then translate it back to its original position. How do I implement this?

I have `glm::lookAt(-lightPos, glm::vec3(0.f), upVector)` but this gives me the light off to the side. This gives me the rotation matrix.

Comment: What do you need for your light? Usually, you need a position and a direction. Both are trivial to get if you know the position and the target.

Comment: I know the position (i can translate it with a gizmo) and its target (origin). Yet, I can't get it to rotate correctly although I do have the correct view matrix for spotlight shadow mapping.

Comment: So you need a view transform... Then why do you use `-camPos` and not just the light's position?

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm already using the `-lightPos` ?

Comment: The code in your questions says `-camPos`. Why would you negate the position?

Comment: Wait, i just re-read your comment from before. Apparently, you already have a working view matrix for the light. So what do you need?

Comment: The original question had a typo in the view matrix - I'm negating the light position. I have correct shadows but my light geometry doesn't rotate which is what I want.

Comment: So you want a model transform. Then just use the inverse of the view transform that you use for shadow mapping.